# How to display only content(image) of a button, not the button itself?

Tags: wpf-controls

i have an image which i am adding it as content for a button. However the window is not getting rendered properly. How can i modify the XAML so that the button shape and color remains hidden but the traiangular image added to the button is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is create a template with only an image and set the button template to it

```
<Style x:Key="ImageButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
         <Image Source="ImageSource.jpg"/> 
      </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Button Template="{DynamicResource ImageButtonStyle}"/>
```

Of course you need to redo all the animations like IsPressed, MouseOver, etc.